# Шаблонная функция

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонная функция:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void function(T1 a, T1 b, T2 c) { ... }
```

Требуется, чтобы 3 параметр имел дефолтное значение. То есть хочется, чтобы было как-то так:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void function(T1 a, T1 b, T2 c = С) { ... }
```

Но при вызове функции от 2 аргументов выдает ошибку. Как я понимаю дело в втором параметре шаблона. Нужно как-то тоже ему придать дефолтное значение.

Comment: Что такое `C`? Какова природа этого `C`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как бы это выразиться... Вы вызываете `f(a,b)` - и что должен делать компилятор, не имея **никакой** информации о типе третьего параметра? Тип тоже надо умолчать...

Что-то вроде:

```
template<typename T, typename U = int>
void f(T a, T b, U c = U(0))
{
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    cout << typeid(c).name() << endl;
    cout << c << endl;

}

int main()
{
    f(0,1,3);
    f(0,1,3.0);
    f(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Аргументы по умолчанию не участвуют в процессе дедукции шаблонных параметров. Поэтому дедукция типа `T2` из вызова функции `function` с двумя аргументами сделана быть не может быть сделана на основе типа `C`.

Пользуйтесь перегрузкой вместо умолчательных аргументов

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void function(T1 a, T1 b, T2 c) 
{ 
  ... 
}

template <class T1>
void function(T1 a, T1 b) 
{
  function(a, b, C);
}
```